# Tree structure in mongodb with parent child relation for read

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to read data in tree structure with nested child of one parent, I am using mongodb. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKoL7.png)

I want this type of expected data from the mongodb 
`[
        {
            "_id": "5d1fd59b1d26b42b2fdecf69",
            "email": "admin@admin",
            "userName": "admin",
            "parrentId": "5d1fd9a6f612542b8d72337d",
            "childs": [
            {
            "_id": "5d1fd61af612542b8d723376",
            "email": "test1@test.com",
            "userName": "test1",
            "parrentId": "5d1fd59b1d26b42b2fdecf69",
            "childs": [
                       {
                       "_id": "5d1fd91af612542b8d723379",
                       "email": "test2@test.com",
                       "userName": "test2",
                        "parrentId": "5d1fd59b1d26b42b2fdecf69",
                        "childs": []
                      },
                      {
                      "_id": "5d1fd91af612542b8d723379",
                      "email": "test2@test.com",
                      "userName": "test2",
                        "parrentId": "5d1fd59b1d26b42b2fdecf69",
                        "childs": []
                        },

                      ]
           }
         ]
        }
]`

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. You've shown output (which you said is what is being generated from what you've done, but then also said it's what you are expecting). It would really help to see what your input data looks like. Please edit to show this, along with what you've tried, and clarifying what the output is (what you're currently getting vs what you're expecting, and how the output shown differs from what you want).

Comment: @DavidMakogo i mistakenly writhed wrong  this type of data I want from mongodb

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Still, without seeing examples of the source collection(s), what you've tried, etc.... the question is still off-topic (it only contains a requirement for output, and nothing that can be "answered").

Comment: basically I creating the tree structure in which one is parent who can invite anothers members , and anothers members also invites another members its so I want a query from which I will able to get childs of childs in nested array which have only one parent

Comment: Right but... there are *many* ways to model such data. And it's impossible to build a query based on documents that you are not showing, or guessing at what your input data looks like. We don't even know if your documents are in the same collection or multiple collections; if they're separate documents or embedded documents; etc. You really have to *edit your question* to show this level of detail. (and please don't add clarifications in comments; they need to be edits to your question). Until then, there's really nothing that can be done here to help.

Comment: tthanks for collaborating with me now I have the image of collections in the question . You can check that image.